# How to import java classes automatically by code?

Tags: java, import, automated-tests, classpath

I want to make an application where I press a button and in the moment of the click all java classes in c:/myClasses/ for example will be imported to the project. I want to import those classes in execution time. Some people told me to use .classpath to make it but I don't know how. I really would like to know how to import these classes automatically.

Explanation: I am making an application to evaluate java classes made from programming students. Basically the idea is to make a junit test case and run it on all classes in a specific folder where students are going to put their classes in. It can seems weird but this is exactly what I need for my research project.

Comment: You can go through the bytecode which has FQNs, I suppose.

Comment: Are the files given by students .class files, or .java files?

Comment: They will be .java

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable "CLASSPATH" to the directory of the classes, and they will be loaded by jvm

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHCGBFB

Comment: I need a way to do it in the exactly moment when I press a button. Just in that moment. Like, the class must be imported just after I click in "Submit". But I don't know how to build this logic.

Answer (score 0):

If students are providing source code (.java) files, you'll need to compile them. While there are ways to integrate a compiler directly into your application, as a simpler way to get started, I'd suggest executing the `javac` compiler as a sub-process.

Once the class is compiled, you can create a class loader, and use it to load the new code. Students could implement and interface, which you invoke, or they could simply write a conventional Java `main` function as an entry point.

Depending on who is submitting code, you might want to set a security manager, or run your application with limited permissions, to avoid a mischievous or even malicious student corrupting your system.

This question is very broad, so you may need to ask new followup questions on particular points.